# Conditional Row Deleting in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, conditional-statements, sql-delete, delete-row

I have a table that contains 4 columns. I need to remove some of the rows based on the Code and ID columns. A code of 1 initiates the process I'm trying to track and a code of 2 terminates it. I would like to remove all rows for a specific ID when a code of 2 comes after a code of 1 and there is not an additional code 1. For example, my current data set looks like this:

```
Code  Deposit    Date        ID
1      $100      3/2/2016    5
2      $0        3/1/2016    5
1      $120      2/8/2016    5
1      $120      3/22/2016   4
2      $70       2/8/2016    3
1      $120      1/3/2016    3
2      $0        6/15/2015   2
1      $120      3/22/2016   2
1      $50       8/15/2015   1
2      $200      8/1/2015    1
```

After I run my script I would like it to look like this:

```
Code  Deposit    Date        ID
1      $100      3/2/2016    5
2      $0        3/1/2016    5
1      $120      2/8/2016    5
1      $120      3/22/2016   4
1      $50       8/15/2015   1
2      $200      8/1/2015    1
```

In all I have about 150,000 ID's in my actual table but this is the general idea.

Comment: And your DB engine is?

Comment: I'm using SQL 2012

Comment: How do you determine when a code comes after a code? It doesn't seem like date is your order column for such action. What determines the action of removing ID = 2 ?

Comment: For each ID number, when a '2' comes after a '1' without another '1', I want to remove all rows with that specific ID number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the ids using logic like this:

```
select t.id
from t
group by t.id
having max(case when code = 2 then date end) > min(case when code = 1 then date end) and -- code 2 after code 1
       max(case when code = 2 then date end) > max(case when code = 1 then date end) -- no code 1 after code2
```

It is then easy enough to incorporate this into a query to get the rest of the details:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.id not in (select t.id
                   from t
                   group by t.id
                   having max(case when code = 2 then date end) > min(case when code = 1 then date end) and -- code 2 after code 1
                          max(case when code = 2 then date end) > max(case when code = 1 then date end)
                  );
```

Answer (score 0):

The approach I took was to add up the Code per each ID.   If it equals 3 exactly, it should be removed.

```
;WITH keepID as (
Select
    ID
    ,SUM(code) as 'sumCode'
From #testInit
Group by ID
HAVING SUM(code) <> 3
)

Select *
From #testInit
Where ID IN (Select ID from keepID)
```

Your post showed keeping ID = 1 which does not seem to fit the criteria ?   Are you sure you would be keeping ID = 1 ?   It only as 2 records with a code of 1 and a code of 2 which adds up to 3 ... thus, remove it.

I just showed the approach in logic ... let me know if you need help with the delete code.

Comment: Oh ... #testInit was the temp table I created with your sample values.

Answer (score 0):

```
delete  from table 
where table.id in

(select id from B where A.id=B.id and B.date>A.date
from 
(select code,id,max(date),id where code=1 group by id) as A,
(select code ,id,max(date),id where code=2 group by id) as B)
```

explanation: select code,id,max(date),id where code=1 as A 
             will fetch  data with the highest date for a specific id of code 1
select code ,id,max(date),id where code=2 group by id) as B
will fetch  data with the highest date for a specific id of code 2

select id from B where A.id=B.id and B.date>A.date wil select all the ids for which the code 2 date is higher than code 1 date.